# Hidden Info in cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing

How do I fix or what do I need to do to hide information in certain cells that have been hidden from printing. I've coloured it white so it is not seen, but when printing it shows and skewers the whole sheet

Comment: What program are you talking about?

Comment: It's Ecxel, so like I mentioned I made the info in the cells white but when printing it shows

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of a set of cells that don't contain privacy information, and also a photo of a printed page to show us the before and after?

Comment: how do I add a screen shot or document

Comment: Upload it somewhere and provide a link. Someone with enough reputation will embed it into your post.

Comment: What's contained in these "hidden" cells? Since they are hidden, can they be moved to outside of the print area?

Comment: Copy to a new Worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple and universal way to hide a cell in a printout and not hide it on the screen.
A universal way to hide content on both the screen and the print is to use custom formatting in the form of three semicolons
`;;;`
This format code hides everything except error values. If errors are a problem, you can hide them (printout only) additionally, description [here](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T006144_Hiding_Errors_on_Printouts).